# How to implement a fast search(2-3 sec) in django containing large dataset?

Tags: django, postgresql, search, django-rest-framework, dataset

I'm working on a project in Django, where I have to find a solution to create a fast search which takes roughly 2 - 3 seconds to load the search result instantaneously. I'm using Django REST API for handing the queries. Currently, I'm getting the result, but it tends to take a lot of time going through the entire database containing a lot of data. I need a solution that I can implement, so that I can reduce the search time to maximum of 3 seconds.
PS. I'm using PostgreSQL as the database.

My motive is to search the city or country and I need to get the results.

**models.py**

```
 class Search(models.Model):
 city = models.CharField('Search Destination', max_length=256, null = true)
 country = models.CharField('Search country', max_length=256, null = true)
 latitude = models.CharField('Search latitude', max_length=256, null = true)
 longitude = models.CharField('Search longitude', max_length=256, null = true)
 createdAt = models.DateTimeField('Created At', auto_now_add=True, null = true)
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

 def __str__(self):
     return self.city
```

**serializers.py**

```
class SearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Search
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class ApiLandingSearchView(generics.ListAPIView):
    search_fields = ['city', country ]
    serializer_class = SearchSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    queryset = Search.objects.all()
```

Comment: Sharing your models and query might help

Comment: Regarding data there is no "do this and it will be fast" approach. Because everything is essentially a tradeoff it is very difficult to give any suggestions without knowing anything about the information on the data types, data volume, hardware specifications or queries being run. Without knowing any of these it is very difficult to give an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a full-text search over your searches via API.

The `SearchFilter` uses the django-admin search functionality in the background, so it's searching for text inside text-fields, which is slow on every database by default.

You will have to add a proper full-text-search to your application.

In your case I see two approaches you can pursue:

- `django-watson`, which is based on the postgres full-text search capabilities
- `django-haystack`, which lets you integrate with elasticsearch

Both you would have to integrate with django-rest-framework by building your own custom Filter-Backend.

Comment: I've decided to continue with Elastic search and it turned out to be extremely fast as required.